# Django login_required decorator not passing "next" value to template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a view on my website require the user to login.

```
@login_required
def checkout(request, campaign_id, artist_id, default_amount):
```

This correctly redirects the user to the view "login" if the user is not logged in when trying to access the view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['usermail']
        password = request.POST['password']
        redirect = request.POST['next']
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

What I want to do is send the user to the page they originally requested after logging in... however, I cannot seem to access the {{next}} variable in my template.

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

When I look at the rendered pages source code, it doesn't get the value for "next":

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value=""/>
```

Even though the URL does have that value:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/?next=/campaign/the-slowdown/vote-for/cut-copy/25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `next` variable in your template, you have to pass it through your `render` function. In your view, add something like:

```
context = {'next': request.GET['next'] if request.GET and 'next' in request.GET else ''}
return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

Then you `{{ next }}` will appear in your template as it does in your URL.

*Also, you can remove both the `else: return render(request, 'login.html')`, as they are obsolete.*

Comment: Worked perfectly. And you are correct I don't need the extra return statements in this case. I previously had them rendering different pages... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To access request vars within your templates you need to use the request context processor, so:

in setttings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...        
)
```

Then in your template you can access the next var:

```
{{ request.GET.next }}
```

Although I would implement this kind of logic in the view, and assign next inside the context instead of accessing it like that inside the template.